# Personal pages domains architecture

Tags: design, architecture, web-development, domain-name-system

We're looking to add personal pages generator for our users, which is simple enough while all of them are on our domain. We also want to enable them to purchase their own domains through us, and serve these pages on their domain.

We currently use Google App Engine for all of our deployment and server needs, and it has been pretty great so far. Now the problem is that I can't really point a domain to single page handler on App Engine, thus I'll have to resort to an external solution.

We can easily handle the pages generation, **the main issue I'm facing is serving a different dynamic page for different domains from a single server.**

What architecture do you suggest? What technologies/platforms should I research?
(We're looking at significant users traffic when this thing is up)

Comment: recommended reading: **[Green fields, blue skies, and the white board - what is too broad?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6961/31260)**

Comment: @gnat added a more focused question

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with a reverse proxy running Nginx or HAProxy with virtual hosts on a bigger Google Cloud VM.  Each of your customers' personal site domains would be directed to the reverse proxy and its virtual hosts would proxy back to the appropriate AppEngine instances.

This way you can serve distinct sites with TLS using SNI.

Other alternatives include Content Delivery Networks (CDNs) like Akamai, CloudFlare, Fastly, and Amazon CloudFront.  I've personally had good experiences with Akamai, but I use it primarily as a Web Application Firewall which is a different ballgame entirely.

Unless the traffic on these personal sites is massive the Nginx/HAProxy solution will hold for quite a long time.  The CDN solution is more for high traffic use cases.  The cost could be prohibitive depending on your revenue model.